# How to run localhost:80 in IIS Express web server?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Below is my appsettings.json configuration.

[image]

When I execute the API I am presented with the error:

```
disco.Error "Error connecting to https://localhost:80/.well-known/openid-configuration. The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.."
```

It seems the port that I set on my AuthConfig does not run and not set on my IIS Express.

Comment: Any reason why you have to use 80?   Why not 8080? (which will probably just work)

Comment: Microsoft last June disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on servers and not clients.  So most likely your client is using TLS 1.0 or 1.1.  Add following static method at beginning of code to use TLS 1.2 : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @Neil I already tried changing my AuthConfig port to 8080 etc...but the error remains the same. It looks like my AuthConfig is not running on IIS Express.

Comment: @jdweng I will try. Thanks guys.